# Where can I find extensive api documentation for phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I know that there's the [official Phonegap API docs site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/index.html).

But, it's missing things like `touchstart` and `touchend`.

Are there any other API documentation sites for Phonegap?
Maybe even the raw docs output?

P.S. Google did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw documentation is located here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/

There are some "to do" items for documentation located here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project %3D CB AND resolution %3D Unresolved AND component %3D Docs ORDER BY priority DESC

I'd encourage you to create an account and submit bug reports for missing documentation.

Also though, I don't think that `touchstart` and `touchend` are part of Cordova but rather browser events - I feel like these are out of the scope of the Cordova documentation.

EDIT: Most of the documentation has been moved out of cordova-docs and into the respective repo, so for example, the most recent "raw" camera documentation is at: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

Try [Phonegap-tips](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html) may be you will find it useful.

Comment: Not exactly what I was aiming for but also a good resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't find that kind of information on the phonegap doc, touchstart, touchend, etc are touch events related to web development, not just phonegap

[Mozilla Touch Events Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Touch_events)

Comment: Yes, but there are other events which are both related to phonegap and web development and are listed in the API..

Comment: that's because they have created the phonegap equivalent to the HTML5 event/function with the same syntax (they follow the W3C API Specifications) and it replaces the HTML5 event/function, so if it isn't in the phonegap API then use the HTML5 event/function and it should work too.